# Generic method to get a list for each Entity Framework class

Tags: c#, entity-framework, generics, reflection

I have this method for my Entity Framework class (v6) to get all the elements in this table from my database:

```
List<FooClass> GetAll_FooClass()
{
    return dbContext.FooClass.ToList();
}
```

So what I would like is a method which would do the same but would be usable on each entity class I have (individually I mean).

Is it possible and if so, how can I implement it ?

**EDIT:** I seem to have mistaken FooClass for a class whereas it is a property of the dbContext object.

```
public class MyDbContext : DbContext
{
    public MyDbContext()
    { }

    public virtual DbSet<FooClass> FooClass { get; set; }
}
```

So I'm trying to use **System.Type** right now (*PropertyInfo* and *MethodInfo*).

Comment: `dbContext.Set<TypeOfEntity>().ToList()`?

Comment: Use @DavidG answer and make your current method generic

Comment: Side note => I think you might look  at some coding conventions because naming like `GetAll_myEntityClass` is so...

Comment: I tried what @DavidG suggested and got this notification from Visual Studio:

**'DbContext.Set<TEntity>' is a method, which is not valid in the given context.**


So I confused the current _FooClass_ which is a property whithin _MyDbContext_ class with the entity class it is named after:


`public class MyDbContext : DbContext
{
        
        public virtual DbSet<FooClass> FooClass { get; set; }
}`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a generic method that takes the type of the entity. For example:

```
public List<TEntity> GetAll<TEntity>() 
    where TEntity : class //This is important as the Set method requires it
{
    //Obviously don't do this, but for completeness:
    var dbContext = new MyContext();

    //And here is the real 'magic':
    return dbContext.Set<TEntity>().ToList();
}
```

To use it, assuming you have a context that looks something like this:

```
public class MyContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Zombie> Zombies { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Human> Humans { get; set; }
}
```

You would call it like this:

```
var allOfTheZombies = GetAll<Zombie>();
```

Comment: Well, now it's working. I don't know what's different (maybe I forgot to use "where T : class"). Thank you !

Comment: I just have to see how to get it working with a mocked (Moq) context in my unit test.